# expo monorepo with expo-yarn-workspaces: how to customize the metro.config.js file

Tags: expo, monorepo, expo-yarn-workspaces

I would like to setup a react-native expo (blank typescript template) project with `monorepo yarn workspaces`. My research on google points me to using this library `expo-yarn-workspaces`. At one step in the tutorial from their website, it is mentioned you must "create" a `metro.config.js` and add the following lines:

```
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require('expo-yarn-workspaces');
module.exports = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);
```

The thing is, in general, in my previous react-native expo projects, I used to add some custom configuration in my `metro.config.js` to get my app import `svg` file as `react components`. This is my custom  configuration:

```
// metro.config.js

const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

My question is: How do I further customise the `metro.config.js` file with custom configuration (such as the above)?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine together [**expo-yarn-workspaces**](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-yarn-workspaces) and [**metro-config**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metro-config) (or [**@expo/metro-config**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@expo/metro-config) if your expo SDK version is v40.0.0 or newer) to configure react native packager. The point is that configuration from expo-yarn-workspaces and its resolver does not export **sourceExts** and you should use another config from metro-config.

Expo SDK v40.0.0 or newer:

```
// metro.config.js
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require('expo-yarn-workspaces');
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const configuration = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      ...configuration.resolver,
      assetExts: configuration.resolver.assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
      // NOTE: using native entrypoint because bug in metro https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/485
      resolverMainFields: ['native', 'module', 'browser', 'main'],
    }
  };
})();
```

Your use case with Expo SDK < v40:

```
// metro.config.js
const { createMetroConfiguration } = require('expo-yarn-workspaces');
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

const configuration = createMetroConfiguration(__dirname);

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      ...configuration.resolver,
      assetExts: configuration.resolver.assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
      // NOTE: using native entrypoint because bug in metro https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/485
      resolverMainFields: ['native', 'module', 'browser', 'main'],
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm working on a different project at the moment and will check your response when I'm back on this one.

Comment: How to have expo restart based on the changes to the workspace packages?